# c++ Visual Studio Output file error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, c++-cli, savefiledialog

I'm creating a text editor for one application, using richtextbox to change the text. I have to add a text file with openfiledialog, then save that file to an output file.

I'm using this code to save my file

```
SaveFileDialog^ saveFile1 = gcnew SaveFileDialog;
if (saveFile1->ShowDialog() == 
    System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK && saveFile1->FileName->Length > 0)
{
  // Save the contents of the RichTextBox1 into the file.
  richTextBox1->SaveFile(saveFile1->FileName);
}
```

but the following string is added to my output file

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1036\fs17
```

I'd like to remove this from my file, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: You are using a [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx), and the output is Rich Text Format (RTF). If you are expecting plain text, perhaps you should be using a plain [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: i m actually using richtextbox to modifie and search in file ,i need to use richtextbox to can do this test and modification    , my text is correct in the richtextbox but when i save it he add this RTF format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the RichTextBox.SaveFile function has a second argument which can be used to specify the format of the file. So instead of calling:

```
richTextBox1->SaveFile(saveFile1->FileName);
```

Try calling it like so:

```
richTextBox1->SaveFile(saveFile1->FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

And this should save the contents as plain text instead of rich text.